# Delete saved game from google play games programmatically

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play-games

We want to use google play games to backup/restore our android game in Unity.
We're using [play-games-plugin-for-unity](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjblYT-35fMAhXJbZoKHXTvCNEQFggdMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fplaygameservices%2Fplay-games-plugin-for-unity&usg=AFQjCNFSjtf4vBrbwm_hDqEIwlghOzxOOQ&sig2=wR9jhO4X5BpQBN0a8zY1gQ)
 for this purpose. 
Using the ShowSelectUI() method, introduced in github, user can manually delete the saved game. 
Now the problem is that we want to provide a button in UI which by clicking user could delete the saved game, is there a way to do the delete operation programmatically?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Provided you know the name of the saved game instance you want to delete, you can call Open, then once you have the metadata for the savedData, call Delete:

```
void DeleteSavedGame(string filename) {
    ISavedGameClient savedGameClient = PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.SavedGame;
    savedGameClient.OpenWithAutomaticConflictResolution(filename, DataSource.ReadCacheOrNetwork,
        ConflictResolutionStrategy.UseLongestPlaytime, OnDeleteSavedGame);
}

public void OnDeleteSavedGame(SavedGameRequestStatus status, ISavedGameMetadata game) {
    ISavedGameClient savedGameClient = PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.SavedGame;
    if (status == SavedGameRequestStatus.Success) {
        // delete the game.
        savedGameClient.Delete(game);
    } else {
        // handle error
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up implementing this per @claytonWilkinson above. Then I added DeleteGoogleCloudSave() to click of a button:

```
public void DeleteGoogleCloudSave(){
    #if UNITY_ANDROID && !UNITY_EDITOR
    Debug.Log("Opening save...");

    if (isGooglePlayGamesConnected()){
        ((PlayGamesPlatform)Social.Active).SavedGame.OpenWithAutomaticConflictResolution("Filename", GooglePlayGames.BasicApi.DataSource.ReadCacheOrNetwork,ConflictResolutionStrategy.UseLongestPlaytime, DeleteSavedGameOpened);
    }
    #endif
}

void DeleteSavedGameOpened(SavedGameRequestStatus status, ISavedGameMetadata meta)
{
    #if UNITY_ANDROID && !UNITY_EDITOR

    Debug.Log("Running SaveGameOpened...");

    if(status == SavedGameRequestStatus.Success)
    {
       DeleteSavedGame();
    }
    #endif
}

void DeleteSavedGame() {
    ISavedGameClient savedGameClient = PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.SavedGame;
    savedGameClient.OpenWithAutomaticConflictResolution("Filename", DataSource.ReadCacheOrNetwork,ConflictResolutionStrategy.UseLongestPlaytime, OnDeleteSavedGame);
}

public void OnDeleteSavedGame(SavedGameRequestStatus status, ISavedGameMetadata game) {
    ISavedGameClient savedGameClient = PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.SavedGame;
    if (status == SavedGameRequestStatus.Success) {
        // delete the game.
        savedGameClient.Delete(game);
        Debug.Log("Google Cloud Save Game has been deleted...");
    } else {
        // handle error
        Debug.LogError("Google Cloud Save Game has NOT been deleted...");
    }
}
```